# Getting error Solve::units

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, units, astronomy

I'm trying to solve the following formula for `i`, given values for all other variables. There are two equations, the first one is a formula to show the transit duraction of a planet, the second one is Kepler's third law.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
G = Quantity[1 , "GravitationalConstant"];
Ms = Quantity[1, "SolarMass"];
Rs = Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"];
P = Quantity[6, "Days"];
Tdur = Quantity[4, "Hours"];

Solve[
  {Tdur == P/π (Sin^-1)[Sqrt[(Rs + Rp)^2 - a^2 (Cos^2)[i]]/a],
   a^3/P^2 == (G Ms)/(4 π^2) }, 
  {i, a}]
```

Mathematica is struggling to create an output as can be seen below and is definitely not solving for `i`. It gives me the error message:

> Solve::units: Solve was unable to determine the units of quantities that appear in the input

Any suggestions what I can do differently are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`UnitConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitConvert.html) on all of the constants

```
G = Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"] // UnitConvert;
Ms = Quantity[1, "SolarMass"] // UnitConvert;
Rs = Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"] // UnitConvert;
P = Quantity[6, "Days"] // UnitConvert;
Tdur = Quantity[4, "Hours"] // UnitConvert;
```

You used the wrong syntax for `ArcSin` and `Cos[i]^2`

```
sol = Solve[{Tdur == P/π*ArcSin[Sqrt[(Rs + Rp)^2 - a^2 Cos[i]^2]/a], 
   a^3/P^2 == (G Ms)/(4 π^2)}, {i, a}, Reals]
```

[image]

Adding constraints on `a` and/or `i` would probably simplify the results.

Comment: thanks for the answer, //Unitconvert doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: On my system, without `UnitConvert` you end up with `SolarRadius` in the result rather than its value in `Meters`. Depends on how you want the result displayed.